# How to get all Sub-string on a String (User Input)

Tags: python, substring

**Code**

```
def substring(word,f,l):
    word_length = len(word)
    l1 = str(word.index(f))
    l2 = str(word.index(l))
    a = word[int(l1):int(l2)+1]
    sub_list = []
    for i in l1:
        for j in l2:
            sub_list.append(a)
    return sub_list

w1 = input("Enter String: ")
w2 = input("Enter start: ")
w3 = input("Enter end: ")
print(substring(w1,w2,w3))
```

**Input**

```
python programming # string
p                  # start
g                  # end
```

**Output**

```
['python prog', 'python prog']
```

**Expected Output**

```
['python prog', 'prog', 'programming']
```

What should I do to get all the substrings on a string base on the user input?

Comment: Why you not added full string? I mean output should be  `['python prog', 'prog', 'programming', 'python programming']`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def substring(line, start, end):
    for i in (start, end):
        if i not in line:
            raise Exception(f"`{i}` not found in `{line}`!")
    start_indexes, end_indexes, sub_list = [], [], []
    line_length, end_length = len(line), len(end)
    for i in range(len(line)):
        if line[i:].startswith(start):
            start_indexes.append(i)
        elif line[i:].startswith(end):
            end_indexes.append(i)
    for i in start_indexes:
        for j in end_indexes:
            right = j + end_length
            if i < right and right-i < line_length:
                sub_list.append(line[i : right])
    return sub_list
```

Output：

```
['python prog', 'prog', 'programming']
```

Comment: It's bad function habit if it return values with different types. You can return just empty list in your guard.

Comment: @LevZakharov You are right. I edited it to raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all occurrences of start and end symbol in your string using regular expression and construct answer with list comprehension:

```
s = input("Enter String: ")
head = input("Enter start: ")
tail = input("Enter end: ")

result = [s[i.start():j.start() + 1] 
          for i in re.finditer(head, s) for j in re.finditer(tail, s)
          if i.start() < j.start()]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['python prog', 'prog', 'programming', 'python programming']
```

Answer (score 0):

`.index()` only gives the first index (and `.rindex()` gives the last index), you want all the indexes, so do `enumerate`, do:

```
def substring(word,f,l):
    word_length = len(word)
    l1 = [i for i,v in enumerate(word) if v==f]
    l2 = [i for i,v in enumerate(word) if v==l]
    sub_list = []
    for i in l1:
        for j in l2:
            sub_list.append(word[i:j+1])
    return sub_list

w1 = input("Enter String: ")
w2 = input("Enter start: ")
w3 = input("Enter end: ")
print(substring(w1,w2,w3))
```

Output:

```
Enter String: python programming
Enter start: p
Enter end: g
['python prog', 'python programming', 'prog', 'programming']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt, using `re` module ([explanation of regexp here](https://regex101.com/r/P9rUqU/1)):

```
import re
from itertools import chain

string = 'python programming' # string
start = 'p'                   # start
end = 'g'                     # end

groups = re.finditer(rf'(?=({start}.*{end}))(?=({start}.*?{end}))', string)
s = set(chain.from_iterable([(g.start(1), g.end(1), g[1]), (g.start(2), g.end(2), g[2])] for g in groups))
print([i[2] for i in s])
```

Prints:

```
['prog', 'python prog', 'programming', 'python programming']
```